# Unable to compile when I upgrade to Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.3

Tags: flutter

I have several error messages when I upgrade my Flutter version to 1.7.8+hotfix.3.

**Here is the message:**

```
Compiler message:
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/svg.dart:158:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'picture failed to precache',
                 ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:335:20: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
          context: 'while resolving a picture',
                   ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:337:33: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
          informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                                ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:432:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:495:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:559:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:256:16: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
      context: context,
               ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:301:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'resolving a single-frame picture stream',
                 ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:399:35: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
            informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                                  ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:408:22: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
            context: 'in _Element.clipPath',
                     ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:798:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                              ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:809:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'in parseSvgElement',
                 ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/utilities/errors.dart:8:32: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
      context: 'in $methodName',
                               ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/utilities/errors.dart:10:29: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
      informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                            ^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 665
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileflutterBuildDebugX86'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 41s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**This is my Flutter Doctor information:**

```
flutter doctor
```

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):     [√]
>   Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.17134.885]) [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android
>   devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)    ! Some Android licenses not
>   accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
>   [√] Android Studio (version 3.2)     [!] IntelliJ IDEA Community
>   Edition (version 2018.2)      X Flutter plugin not installed; this
>   adds Flutter specific functionality.      X Dart plugin not installed;
>   this adds Dart specific functionality. [√] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
>   [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your version of `flutter_svg` to at least 0.13.0 in your `pubspec.yml`

Comment: Thanks mate it worked. flutter_svg's latest version is 0.13.1. Published Jul 10, 2019 [UNIDENTIFIED]. Its unidentified now. Should i find another package for svgs?

Comment: @CanKarabag Don't worry about it. That is just because the new version of Flutter just released. The plugin should work fine.